# Why are bisexual women more supported then bisexual men in the USA?

Tags: united-states, lgbt+

I was reading an [pew paper](https://www.pewsocialtrends.org/2013/06/13/chapter-2-social-acceptance/) from 2013 on LGBT community and came across a graph about how the LGBT community, in general, deemed each subgroup was accepted.

[image]

I was surprised that bisexual women were rated as significantly more accepted then bisexual men with bi women having 33% believe there is a lot of acceptance for them while bisexual men only warranted 8% in the same category.

I was wondering if someone could explain why sex plays such a significant role on level of acceptance for bi individuals within the LGBT community.

I see that lesbian women are ranked as more accepted to gay men, so perhaps society is just more accepting of women having sex with women then men with other men, but that doesn't explain why by women are more supported then lesbians but bi men are less supported then gay men.

Comment: This is a widely known phenomenon, but not really politics? Sociology, maybe

Comment: Do note that this is a survey of the *perception* of LBGTQ people in general about which groups are most accepted, not an actual measure of which groups are most accepted. There is some relationship between the two (since LBGTQ people generally have a good idea about discrimination against them) but it's going to be loose, so I am not sure you can judge from a 6% point difference in perception (probably with a margin of error of 3% for each individual number and 6% net) that bisexual women are definitely more accepted than gay men.

Comment: A direct survey of attitudes of the general population towards each group would probably be more determinative (although also more marred by desirability bias, I imagine). Anyway, one reason that at least some heterosexual people accept bisexual women more than gay men is that they perceive female-female sex as arousing, but male-male sex as icky or even threatening. Something similar happens with gay couples in some fiction written by heterosexual women. Of course, men have more power in most societies, so if there were a statistical difference in acceptance, that might be a source.

Comment: Another reason might be that there exists a perception among some people that if sex does not involve penile penetration, it doesn't "count" (unfortunately sometimes extending even to denying abuse and assault).

Comment: Bluntly?  Perhaps you could look up figures on the number of men who fantasize about having a threesome with two bisexual women.

Comment: @jamesqf - Indeed, that is basically what I said. Except I meant to write "heterosexual men," and I wrote "heterosexual people" instead, so the implication is less clear. Also, for whatever reason I read the question too quickly and thought that it was asking about bisexual women vs. gay men, but a lot of the same reasons apply.

Comment: You're trying to group cohorts by sexual orientation, but the data you present looks more like it breaks down along gender lines first, and *then* sexual orientation lines. That's honestly not very surprising, as society tends to think about female and male sexuality in very different terms.

Comment: The q could be marginally on-topic on psychology SE... but don't blame me if other regulars there are going to think otherwise...

Comment: There is also some evidence that bisexuality *is* more common in women, which of course affects how many present themselves that way, which would affect perception. I am not sure I am wholly convinced but I think it's robust enough to not entirely dismiss out of hand

Comment: The bible is big in the US, and it prohibits men with men, but says nothing about women. There's also prejudice against bi men from gay men, and a huge chunk of the survey-taking LGBT population is gay men, so they have outsized impact on those particulr numbers.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- what evidence are you referring to? Kinsey found American men less sexually polar than women.

Comment: @dandavis - While a strict reading of the Old Testament would indicate that it prohibits only men having sex with men, and maybe even only male anal sex, most religious fundamentalist and Catholic Christians seem to interpret it as a license to dislike lesbian and bisexual women as well. As an amusing side note: a super literal interpretation of the verse would prohibit women having sexual intercourse with men and limit them to having sex with only women. So much for evangelical devotion to Biblical literalism.

Comment: @dand I don't remember, but it was more recent than Kinsey, lol

Comment: @Obie2.0 There is one verse that does strongly imply lesbianism is a biblical no no, even if it doesn't say it explicitly.  Forget the exact phrasing but it basically says women should avoid sexual deviancy then goes on to say something like "similarly men shouldn't be sexual deviants by having sex with other men".  So while it doesn't explicitly say women/women sex is wrong the implication is that the sexual deviancy women should avoid from the first sentence is homosexuality since it's similar to the male homosexuality condemned in the very next passage.